# Typescript: modules with functions being interpreted as promises

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I'm am using an npm module called clear to write a CLI application.

The clear module is very simple:

```
module.exports = function clear(opts) {
    if (typeof (opts) === 'boolean') {
      opts = { fullClear: opts }
    }

    process.stdout.write('\x1b[0f');
};
```

So it's a really simple module.  However when I call the function in my code, like this:

```
const clear = import('clear')

clear()
```

I get the following error message:

> This expression is not callable.
>    Type 'Promise<(opts?: ClearOptions) => void>' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

The same is true for any other module that exports functions.

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./typings", "node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".vscode", "./typings"]
}
```

Were am I going wrong?

---

**Update:**

If I change the import statement to `const clear = require('clear')` then it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The `import` function [returns a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports), because its execution is deferred. It is used for dynamic imports (e.g. when you want to conditionally import a module based on some condition, or when you have a circular dependency between two or more modules).

It seems that what you actually want is an `import` *statement*:

```
import clear from 'clear';
```

Comment: Yes of course, I was getting the syntax confused between require and import statements.  Also, turned out I need to add: "esModuleInterop": true to my tsconfig.json file.  Thanks for your help!